# How do I give this slash command options in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I have this set up to take options that I predefine for the user rather than them needing to type it in themselves?

````
@bot.tree.command(name="alerttype", description="Options: The Gathering Legions, World Boss, The Helltide Rises, All Alerts")
    async def alerttype(interaction: discord.Interaction, alert_type: str):
    
        if interaction.guild is None:
            await interaction.response.send_message("This command cannot be used in a DM.")
            return
    
        if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.manage_channels:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You do not have the required permissions to execute this command.")
            return
    
        if alert_type not in ["The Gathering Legions", "World Boss", "The Helltide Rises", "All Alerts"]:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Invalid alert type. Please try again.")
            return
    
        c.execute("UPDATE Channels SET alert_types = ? WHERE guild_id = ?", (alert_type, interaction.guild.id))
        conn.commit()
    
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Alert type set to {alert_type}.")
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this question you can use a literal to show a list of options:

```py
bot.tree.command(name="alerttype", description="Options: The Gathering Legions, World Boss, The Helltide Rises, All Alerts")
async def alerttype(interaction: discord.Interaction, alert_type: Literal["The Gathering Legions", "World Boss", "The Helltide Rises", "All Alerts"]):
        if interaction.guild is None:
            await interaction.response.send_message("This command cannot be used in a DM.")
            return
    
        if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.manage_channels:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You do not have the required permissions to execute this command.")
            return
    
        if alert_type not in ["The Gathering Legions", "World Boss", "The Helltide Rises", "All Alerts"]:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Invalid alert type. Please try again.")
            return
    
        c.execute("UPDATE Channels SET alert_types = ? WHERE guild_id = ?", (alert_type, interaction.guild.id))
        conn.commit()
    
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Alert type set to {alert_type}.")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so very much. I have been trying to figure this out for some time now.